# How to search for where someone else was mentioned on Slack?

Tags: search, slack

Suppose another Slack account is `@John Doe`.

Is it possible to search a Slack workspace for instances where John Doe was @-mentioned? I've noticed that searching `"John Doe"` or `"@John Doe"` doesn't work, and only returns instances where the main body of the message contains those words.

If I search `to:@John Doe` it only picks up the direct messages I sent to him. But I want to see instances where other people @-mentioned him in public channels.

Comment: have you tried to copy an existing `@John Doe` mention into the search field?

Comment: @LittleBit I hadn't, but that works well. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible by copying an existing `@John Doe` mention or typing a mention directly into he search field.

Note: It must be an interactive mention, simply typing the text "@John Doe" does not match `@John Doe`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Typing a mention didn’t seem to work, but copy/pasting did.

Comment: Type the first few characters of `@JohnDoe` into the search bar. When you see an autocomplete option of a magnifying glass followed by `@John Doe`, click on it. (Do not press the enter key, and do not click on an autocomplete option if it doesn't have the magnifying glass.)

Answer (score 0):

In my testing it had nothing to do with cut and pasting, when I do:

- @username - it does a string search for that token (in all DMs, Threads and channels)
- to:@myusername - It searches DMs sent to me.
- to:@diffusername - It searches messages I sent.

In each of these cases it is not sufficient to just type @ followed by the username - you have to force slack to pop up the list of users and select the relevant person from the list (hence the name gets the blue highlight).

For clarify - you get different results, if you include the modifier **to:**

PS The best docs I found (which don't cover **to:**) were here:
https://slack.com/help/articles/202528808-Search-in-Slack